# How does negative power of laurent series vanish?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose the function is an analytic function on $\{\omega={z:0<|z|\le 1}$}.Moreover $f$ satisfies $ |f(z)| \le \frac{1}{|z|^{1/2}}|\sin(\frac{1}{|z|})|$ for all $z$ in $\omega$. $a_n$ is the coefficient of Laurent series. I want to show that $a_n$ is zero for negative $n$. I apply Cauchy-Goursat thereom since $f(z)(z)^n$ for positive n is analytic on the annulus except for one point. Is this valid?

Comment: Define $a_n$. Are you talking about Laurent series expansion?

Comment: yes. it is laurent series expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r \in (0,1)$ and let $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n \le -1$. We have

$a_n= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}} dw$.

An easy estimation gives

$|a_n| \le r^{-n-1/2} \sin(1/r)$.

Since $r \in (0,1)$ was arbitrary and $\sin(1/r)$ is bounded, we get with $r \to 0$ that $a_n=0$.

Comment: Is it because the series expansion has to be valid for all r and is unique in the annulus , so you can take limit r tends to zero and get the answer?

Comment: Yes, we have for each(!) $r \in (0,1)$ that $a_n= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}.$

Comment: what is the meaning of(!)?

Comment: It is an emphasis on the word "each".